# Showing there is exactly one subgroup of SO(2) of order n for every n

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

For the $SO(2)$, I want to show that there is precisely one subgroup of order $n$ for every natural $n$. I can see the obvious case of the identity subgroup of order 1, but from here I get stuck. What would a subgroup of order 2 even look like? What other rotation of the circle would be in this subgroup? Is it some arbitrary multiple $2\pi r$ for some $0 < r \leq 1$? I am having trouble visualizing this.

An idea I've had is that these finite order subgroups should be cyclic, i.e. the subgroup of order 2 looks like $G = \{ I, A_{\pi} \}$, where $I$ is the identity and $A_{\pi}$ is the rotation matrix for a rotation of angle $\pi$. Then the subgroup of order $n$ would be that which contains $2\pi$ divided into $n$ rotations, but I'm unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: You already correctly identified the subgroups. What remains is to prove that they are the only ones of their respective order. Note that the one-dimensional complex representation may be useful as it allows you to recast it as algebraic problem.

Comment: Do you mean using Euler's formula? I imagine I should assume there are two subgroups of a given order, and then prove that they  are in fact the same subgroup.

Comment: Yes, essentially it's using Euler's formula. The group multiplication then just reduces to multiplication of complex numbers.

Comment: Essentially, the fundamental theorem of algebra tells you how many elements of order $p$ you can have. Given the factorization of finite abelian groups into cyclic groups, you can do the same for groups of order $n$, and compare.